# What about FontAwesomes icons make they un-highlightable?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

What about FontAwesomes icons make they un-highlightable? And how can I replicate that? Is it the `before` attribute?

Comment: [Here are a ton of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/1979005). This applies to all content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `user-select:none;` for that with the appropiate prefixes. See here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none

Chrome working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/59NzS/